# Running my app on different platforms

Tags: visual-studio, setup-deployment, visual-studio-cordova

I installed Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio but can’t for the life of me figure out how to run my app on different platforms.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information can be found on the [FAQ](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398476) page:

To switch between target device platforms, you will need to use the “Solution Platforms” dropdown present in the VS toolbar. If you have installed a fresh copy of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, it will be there by default, but it may not be present if you upgraded from a previous version.

Explained in detail: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2954109